# How do I get a "Sign in with Facebook" button in Denmark?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I live in Denmark.

In connection with a project I would like to add a "Sign in with Facebook" button to a website. In order to do that I apparently have to register as a Facebook developer on https://developers.facebook.com/.

But during the registration process, they need to confirm my cell phone number by sending me a confirmation code in a text message. I never receive that code. As far as I can tell, Facebook does not support text messages to Denmark. (If you go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=mobile and press "Activate Text Messaging," you will get a list of supported countries. They include countries like Tajikistan and the Democratic Republic of Congo, but *not* Denmark.)

Facebook support has been less than helpful.

Can anybody suggest what I can possibly do? Do I really need to emigrate just to get a "Sign in with Facebook" button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook give you 2 options for verification.

Verify via SMS or adding a credit card

https://www.facebook.com/help/167551763306531

(The option 2 on that page gives a link where to add your card for verification)

Failing both of them, you might be able to get a VOIP/virtual number which might forward the SMS/call to your own phone.

Comment: Perfect, Adam! Thank you so much! Adding a credit card worked perfectly.